# Remove plot margins for area plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have these data

[image: Pandas DF]

and I plot like:

```
df.plot.area()
plt.margins(0, 0)
plt.show()
```

which gives me this:

[image: Plot]

The result is cool but how do I get rid of the top white margin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course the obvious solution is to set the y limits.

```
plt.ylim(0,1)
plt.margins(0, 0)
```

The drawback of this is that the limits need to be known.

The more general solution, which does not require to know the limits beforehands, is to first let the plot autoscale, then set the margins,

```
plt.autoscale()
plt.margins(0, 0)
```

In both cases, the result would look like

[image]